# JSON array javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to store 3 pet names in `string` format, parse them into array and later read one by one

Example

```
pets = '{{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{name:"joe"}}';

var arr = JSON.parse(pets);

alert(arr[0].name);
```

But it doesn't work.

Also I would need to add entry to array (probably with **push**) but I am having problems too.

Someone has idea how to do it?

Comment: Probably because you've got objects in objects and it's going to be arr[0][0].name

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed.  Try this:

```
var pets = '{"pets":[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]}';
var arr = JSON.parse(pets);
alert(arr.pets[0].name);
```

Comment: Why should another layer be added. Also there is explanation of what was wrong with the JSON from the question. Please explain what you did find wrong.

Answer (score 18):

JSon arrays are bounded by [] brackets

try

```
pets = '[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]';
```

also you forgot to use "'s on the last property name.

Comment: To be clear, if I paste your code exactly and go into jsfiddle and add this:
alert(pets[0].name);

it is undefined. forEach doesn't work either.

Answer (score 14):

A simpler JSON array (an array of strings):

```
["jack", "john", "joe"];
```

Putting it together as JavaScript:

```js
var pets = '["jack", "john", "joe"]';
var arr = JSON.parse(pets);
console.log(arr[0]); // jack
console.log(arr[1]); // john
console.log(arr[2]); // joe
```

Answer (score 8):

yes just change it to this square brackets also check the double quotations on the last element

```
pets = '[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(pets);

alert(arr[0].name);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pets = '[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(pets);

alert(arr[0].name);
```

Comment: Please supply an explanation with your code.  code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Downvoted because this is obviously a simple copy of @amir-magdy answer.

Answer (score -1):

An Array must always be written inbetween square brackets

```
pets = [{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{name:"joe"}];
var arr = JSON.parse(pets);
alert(arr[0].name);
```

Comment: How is this different from earlier answers?

Comment: Downvoted because this is obviously a simple copy of @amir-magdy answer.