# How to return JSON encoded array, receive the array and parse it so it can be used in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

My PHP finds a bunch of urls for images. I want to be able to display them on an app. I'm using AJAX to retrieve the returned array. Then I'm trying to parse it and put it into a javaScript array. Then I want to display the first image from it's URL with my build image function. Currently no images are displayed. I'm not sure where my issue is, I don't think the array is being parsed and I'm not even sure if it's returning correctly in the php.

Below is my PHP. Using JSON ecode and trying to return that array of paths.

```
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");
$select_query = "SELECT `ImagesPath` FROM `offerstbl` ORDER by `ImagesId` DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());   


$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
$data[] = $row['ImagesPath'];
}

echo json_encode( $data );

?>
```

This is a idea of what is echoed and hopefully returned.

["http://server/~name/folder/images/07-08-2014-1407418088.png","http://server/~name/folder/images/05-08-2014-1407252096.png"]

This is my script using AJAX to take that array and parse it into an javaScript array.

```
      function importJson(str) {



            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }



            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {


            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                alert("onreadystatechange");
                var images = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    buildImage(images[i]);
            }
            }
            }


            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://server/~name/folder/content.php");
            xmlhttp.send();

            buildImage=function(src) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = src;
                document.getElementById("content").appendChild(img);

            }
      }

    window.onload = importJson();

  </script>
```

The first image should be placed in the div contents.

```
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON array javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419303/json-array-javascript)

Comment: The issue here, is trying to change PHP to a JSON and parse it correctly. I'm having difficulty i think with outputting the JSON message and receiving. Parsing maybe also but much more complex than that example.

Comment: I believe I'm sending or receiving the whole php script instead of just the array?

Answer (score 0):

It looks mostly good.  You're encoding the data with json_encode and parsing it in JS with JSON.parse.  That's correct.

Take advantage of your Javascript debugging tools like Chrome's "Developer Tools".  Check the network(Net) tab in order to 1. make sure the AJAX request is being sent by your browser, 2. The response is received, and 3. the response data is formatted the way you expect it to be.

If you're receiving the data and it's correct, then something is going on in your parsing of the responseText.  Slap a "debugger;" line in there and play with the result.

Also, you should probably add an else to the if statement checking the response.

```
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    ...
 } else {
   alert("Error");
 }
```

Otherwise your app would silently fail if the server returns an invalid response.

Comment: I added else error into the if statement underneath the for loop for creating the images and I get three error alerts. One for every image in the array I assume. I assume that means Im not parsing the array correctly.

Comment: Actually, I think that would suggest something wrong in the request-response cycle.  Each alert would be for the different ready states.
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready

Comment: I believe it is. The  "alert("onreadystatechange");" in my above code does become active after three error messages.

Comment: I also believe the second if statement in the importJson function, is working but not the first.

Comment: `if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
`
That if statement you mean?  You're not passing in an empty string so it's not going to pass (str == "").

Comment: That's correct. Why am I getting three error alerts? I assume something is not correct with my readyState?

Comment: If ran in a browser, I get an error saying "unexpected token <" for the line "var images = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);"

Comment: Ok, that error means there's something wrong with xmlhttp.responseText.  Could you find out what that value is?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 

</html>["http:\/\/server\/~name\/folder\/images\/22-08-2014-1408726981.jpg","http:\/\/server\/~name\/folder\/images\/07-08-2014-1407418088.png"]

Comment: The above is what xmlhttp.responseText looks like?

Comment: Ah, okay, there's the problem.  Because AJAX requests are for retrieving html pages, XMLHttpRequest is automatically adding tags.  You need to tell it that you want to process JSON data.  See the part [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Handling_binary_data) about handling binary data.

I think you need to set:
`xmlhttp.responseType = "json";`

And possibly use .response instead of .responseText

Comment: I'm not a hundred % sure where I should be declaring xmlhttp.responseType = "json"; but I don't think it's stoping the automatic tags.

Comment: The response now comes back as null

Comment: `xmlhttp.responseType = "json";`
should go before: `xmlhttp.send();`

Looking into this more, I realize that the browser will automatically parse the response as json, so you no longer need JSON.parse, but you do need to use xmlhttp.response instead of xmlhtt.responseText (which would be null).